# Completely clean reset of Mac—does Internet Recovery reset Recovery partition

Tags: disk-utility, ssd, recovery, internet-recovery, recovery-hd

I want to completely reset my Mac by wiping the entire SSD.

I plan to start up from Internet recovery and then use Disk Utility's `Erase` option to erase `APPLE SSD AP0512M Media` (my computer has a 512 GB SSD).

If I do this, will I be able to reinstall MacOS from Internet Recovery (if my entire SSD is wiped)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of Internet Recovery is to allow reinstallation of the OS when all data on the internal storage is lost, including the Recovery partition.

However, some people have had trouble with some models of Macs not connecting to Apple servers. It's certainly worthwhile making sure you've got an external bootable install media for emergencies.

Also, there's not really any point in 'resetting' the Recovery partition and the entire disk itself: erasing the system/user volume and reinstalling using the Recovery partition will suffice to put the Mac back to a 'brand new' state.

Comment: The [Apple website](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208496#erasedisk) says that before giving away your mac, you should erase the entire SSD. Does this remove the recovery partition?

Comment: Yes, it does. But there's no personal information there. Just erasing the Container disk1 is sufficient.

Comment: There's no point in resetting Recovery partition on purpose, but it might be corrupted (by malicious person, for example) so it'd be nice to make sure that Recovery is in its intended state before giving away the device.